# Improving for-each performance

Tags: java, android, arrays, foreach

I have the following `CountDownTimer` running constantly at my Android Application.

```
CountDownTimer timer_status;
timer_status = new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

    List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int k=0;
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        String S = "";
        k=0;
        byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[8];

        for (int value : lst) {

            if(k==8) {
                k=0;
                S="";
             }

            S = S + String.format("%02x ", value).toUpperCase();
            writeBuffer[k] = (byte) value;
            k++;

        }

        editSent.setText(S);                            
}
```

Every loop, the application creates a new `byte[]` buffer from a `List` of Integers.

It work's fine, but is generating `GC_FOR_ALLOC` at LogCat.

```
03-05 11:12:41.330: D/dalvikvm(21178): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 19% free 4662K/5720K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-05 11:12:42.250: D/dalvikvm(21178): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 19% free 4662K/5720K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
```

> GC_FOR_ALLOC is triggered because there wasn't enough memory left on the heap to perform an allocation. Might be triggered when new objects are being created.

How can I improve this `foreach` loop leaving enough memory on the heap?

Comment: When you use String like this, it creates unique String each time and put those in String Pool. Use StringBuilder for better performance.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good way to start improving it.

Comment: Use the static final for magic numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
 k=0; 
 byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[8];

 for (int value : lst) { 
 if(k==8) { k=0; sb.setLength(0); 
 } 
 sb.append(String.format("%02x ", value)); 

 writeBuffer[k] = (byte) value; k++; 
 }

 editSent.setText(sb.toString().toUpperCase());
```

Apart from `StringBuilder`, I would like to point out that normal `for` has better performances than `foreach` in Android because the `foreach` loop creates a hidden `Iterator` object. So avoid using for-each in performance critical code in Android.

Also, if possible use normal `Array` for primitive types rather than `ArrayList` as autoboxing/unboxing would take place in each loop which would affect your performance.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate how StringBuilder would fit in my context?

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        k=0;
        byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[8];

        for (int value : lst) {

            if(k==8) {
                k=0;
                sb.setLength(0);
            }
            sb.append(String.format("%02x ", value).toUpperCase());
            writeBuffer[k] = (byte) value;
            k++;
        }
        editSent.setText(sb.toString());

Answer (score -1):

Using a StringBuilder is the one thing (see comment).

You can also avoid the local variables `S` and `writeBuffer` and use class variables instead, which effectively reuses both with each call instead of passing them to the garbage collection.

Comment: Why would a class variable `S` be better? I think that's just plain wrong... (Additionally it would lead to the String behind `S` to be referenced longer than needed!)

Comment: If there's a problem with garbage collection, the key is preventing garbage. If you know you need a variable very often, it would be a lot more efficient to declare it once, keep it with the class, and clean it after each use. And clean means clean, not set to null (which again passes it to GC).

Comment: I believe it's not the case since they're going to be used constantly, not very often, as you mentioned.